# MySQL JSON_EXTRACT path expression error

Tags: mysql, json

The syntax looks right to me, any help would be appreciated!

```
mysql> select fieldnames from tablename limit 5;
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| fieldnames                                             |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| {"example-field-1": "val2"}                            |
| {"example-field-2": "val1"}                            |
| {"example-field-1": "val1", "example-field-3": "val1"} |
| {"example-field-2": "val1"}                            |
| {"example-field-2": "val2"}                            |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
mysql> select JSON_EXTRACT(fieldnames, '$.example-field-1') from tablename;
ERROR 3143 (42000): Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 17 in '$.example-field-1'.
```

MySQL 5.7.10

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Can you try this advice from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

> As mentioned previously, path components that name keys must be quoted
> if the unquoted key name is not legal in path expressions. Let $ refer
> to this value.

```
select JSON_EXTRACT(fieldnames, '$."example-field-1"') from tablename;
```

NOTE

If you have more fields, you must quote each key not the whole path:

```
select JSON_EXTRACT(fieldnames, '$."field"."example-field-1"') from tablename;
```

Comment: Thank you! That was it. The quotes inside the quotes.

Comment: I really wish the Mysql documents would highlight that more. This answer did spare me from going down a rabbit hole.

Comment: For compact syntax it seems like you should quote the entire path: `fieldnames->"$.field.example-field-1"` (with mysql8.0 at least)

Comment: Pure luck to have stumbled on this. Worth noting this issue also exist in MySQL 8 but not in MariaDB 10 (at least 10.4 for me, not tested on other versions)