# How To check If mysql DB column has json array of object and contains specific string

Tags: mysql, json, database

I have saved the json data in mysql database column which looks like below

> [{"one":"mg road plot number 711 xyz"},{"two":"dc road plot number 711 xyz"}]

json data like above is being stored for all the records with different address. So what I am trying to do is , I want to search all the customer who are having address of mg road.

So I have tried **JSON_SEARCH** and **JSON_CONTAINS** but it always returning me no records found even though there are 2 records in a table. So where I am going wrong.

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_clients_data` WHERE JSON_SEARCH(reci_address,'all', "mg road")


SELECT * FROM `tbl_clients_data` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(reci_address, 'mg road', '$.one')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try this code:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_clients_data` WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(reci_address, '$[*].one') 
LIKE 'mg road%' OR JSON_EXTRACT(reci_address, '$[*].two') LIKE 'mg road%'
```

JSON_EXTRACT Extracts data from a JSON document. The extracted data is selected from the parts matching the path arguments. Returns all matched values; either as a single matched value, or, if the arguments could return multiple values, a result autowrapped as an array in the matching order.

Comment: i just tried it returns 0 rows and  shows error like ===Warning: #4038 Syntax error in JSON text in argument 1 to function 'json_extract' at position 31

Comment: it;s still the same with 0 rows and same warning/error

Comment: The error should have not been there , here is a reference to that error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35735454/mysql-json-extract-path-expression-error

Comment: thank you for the link..but still its giving empty result,,